# Is the word 'parameterizable' an incorrect variation of 'parametric'?

Tags: meaning

In other words, are all [these](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=parameterizable+site:books.google.com&start=0) uses incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that both words refer to something that can be parametrised, although parametrise is not taken in the exact same sense.

In mathematics and physics, *parametric* means that something can be controlled by a finite set of parameters. Often, you can make choices for this set of parameters, e.g. the plane can be *parametrised* by abscissa and ordinate of points, or by the distance and bearing angle relative to some origin. But you will not introduce new possibilities by doing so, it is just another set of controls for the same thing.

In technology and IT, *parametrisable* (also spellt *parameterisable, parametrizable, parameterizable*) means that values that would by default be regarded as unalterable constants can optionally be turned into tunable parameters.

It makes sense then that different suffixes are used: *-ic* to describe the state of something being controlled by parameters, *-able*, able to be parametrised.

Comment: Did you mean to write _parameterisable_ rather than _parametrisable_? The latter seems to be even more obscure.

Comment: Well, Oxford dictionary notes that both variants on the verb are found (although they don't quote the -ise version, which is recognised by my BE spell checker, which btw doesn't admit the version with the 'e'). So I'd say these are just minor spelling variants of the same word.

Comment: Also more often with a *z* instead of an *s* on this side of the pond.

Comment: @RBarryYoung
 Oh, **_that_** side.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We prefer to call it ***thiz*** side.

Comment: @RBarryYoung And it must be conceded that you drive on the right side.